# error in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I am writing an query in sql and getting an error:

```
Invalid use of group function
```

What does it mean?
In my query, where clause is given below:

```
select c.name,s.contact,s.number
from list c , senior s
where c.id = s.id AND c.name = 'Abg' AND c.state ='qw' AND MIN(c.dob);
```

Basically, I have 2 files and I need to find the younger customer from 2nd file and then have to retrieve its data from first file. I have the ID number of customers in 2nd file. I first check the ids with the id of first file. And check its state and name. And then I need to find younger among those customers.Thats Why i need MIn function.

Comment: maybe it's helpful you post the whole query(?)

Comment: Agreed. The error is probably happening right before the WHERE clause.. maybe a table named group or something?

Comment: Could you provide the complete query? I expect somewhere to find a 'GROUP BY' clause, causing this error to be thrown.

Comment: The error is in the And MIN(c.dob) part. What does that even mean? Find me records where the lowest value of c.dob... is incomplete. What he needs is to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a subquery:

```
 select c.name,s.contact,s.number
 from  from list c, senior s
 inner join
 (
    select MIN(c.dob) minDob
           ,c.id
    from list c
    where c.id = s.id AND c.name = 'Abg' AND c.state ='qw'
    group by c.id 
 ) sq
 on c.dob = sq.minDob
    and c.id = sq.id
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND MIN(c.dob);` is causing the error.

I think you should use something like:

```
c.dob = (select MIN(dob) from c);
```

Comment: "And then I need to find younger among those customers." implies the where constrains should be used when finding the min value of dob.